# https session login/logout with java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, https, content-management-system

Just a very simple question.  I have set up a rather simple CMS in JSP.  All I need is a security measure to maintain the system's privacy.  Does anyone know of any tutorials that assist in building https sessions for simple networks??

I have more or less conquered (or grasped) the main portions of building databases, using CRUD, and making the programs interact between the java code and the JSP.  This is basically the final hurdle before I can securely and confidently launch this thing and get it going.

Any and all information is always appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a class called SSLSession that you can use:

[This is the tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/SSLClientSession.htm)

[This is the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSession.html)

Comment: Thanks, will look into it.  Appreciate the reference and example.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into session management closely if your site is critical. In simple terms, make a form to get username/password. If they match, use jsp's

To login :

```
session.setAttribute("login", "true");
```

To check if the user is logged in,

```
boolean logged = session.getAttribute("login") != null
```